# column have range values example 1-3 , 1-5 , 1-100 , how to convert this range into comma separated values example for 1-3 i need 1,2,3 in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

input (1-3)
(1-5)

expected output (1,2,3)
(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `range`:

```py
def function(start, end):
    return list(range(start, end+1))
```

Then `function(1,3)` would return `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful.

```
>>> data = (['1-3'], ['1-5'])
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=['ranges'])
>>> df.show()
+------+
|ranges|
+------+
|   1-3|
|   1-5|
+------+

>>> split_col = func.split(df['ranges'], '-')
>>> df = df.withColumn('from', split_col.getItem(0))
>>> df = df.withColumn('to', split_col.getItem(1))
>>> df.show()
+------+----+---+
|ranges|from| to|
+------+----+---+
|   1-3|   1|  3|
|   1-5|   1|  5|
+------+----+---+

>>> df = df.withColumn("from", df["from"].cast(IntegerType()))
>>> df = df.withColumn("to", df["to"].cast(IntegerType()))
>>> df.withColumn('ranges', func.sequence('from', 'to')).show()
+---------------+----+---+
|         ranges|from| to|
+---------------+----+---+
|      [1, 2, 3]|   1|  3|
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|   1|  5|
+---------------+----+---+
```